# How to place vertices evenly spaced along a path\curve using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

How would I go about placing vertices spaced evenly along a path or curve? I've looked at the Extrude Along Path addon, but I don't get the math, and it's doing more than I want to do. To be more specific, I need to know how to get the location of where to place the each vertex.

Comment: Why use python?

Comment: Because I'm writing an addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathutils module has an [interpolate_bezier](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier) function that will give you a list of points along a curve.

```
import bpy
from mathutils.geometry import interpolate_bezier

res = 5 # number of points to get

src_spline = bpy.data.objects['BezierCurve'].data.splines[0]

k1 = src_spline.bezier_points[0].co
h1 = src_spline.bezier_points[0].handle_right

k2 = src_spline.bezier_points[1].co
h2 = src_spline.bezier_points[1].handle_left

points = interpolate_bezier(k1, h1, h2, k2, res)

for p in points:
    o = bpy.data.objects.new('p', None)
    o.location = p
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(o)
```